# Can I use Chrome Web Store payments with OAuth 2.0

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-chrome-app, google-api-dotnet-client

I've written a hosted Chrome Web App which authenticates the user with OAuth 2.0 using the Google APIs Client Library for .NET. Now I want to add payments to our application using the in-built Chrome Web Store Payments.

Looking at [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/check_for_payment#userid) it appears that I need an OpenID URL in order to check for payment.

How can I get this UserID/OpenID URL since I'm using OAuth instead of OpenID authentication?

```
var service = new Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
        ApplicationName = "My App Name",
    }
);
HttpResponseMessage message = await service.HttpClient.GetAsync(
    string.Format("https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1/licenses/{0}/{1}", 
        appId,
        fedId // Where do I get this??
    )
);
```

Comment: Where do you retrieve the `usercredential` variable?

Comment: `userCredential` is the individual user's OAuth token which I retrieve through the `IAuthorizationCodeFlow` process as per the Google Client Library. This is the user whose licence I want to validate.

Comment: Have you configured the OpenID via the [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid?csw=1)?

Comment: I'm not using OpenID or Google App Engine. I'm writing a hosted app using .NET and OAuth 2.0

Comment: If you read this [https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp) I am sure you could solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wanted to leave my own experience here so that others can see that it's not just a matter of using the existing Id returned from an authorised request to the user profile endpoint, as this is not the ID required by the Chrome Payments API...

#### Short Answer

It's not possible to use **only** OAuth2.0 for a hosted app. The only options for a hosted app are:

- Use the deprecated OpenID (see detailed answer)
- Use In-app Payments using Google Wallet for Digital Goods

#### Long Answer

We still have to use OpenID, however Google has provided a migration path for OpenID users to OAuth2.0 called [OpenID Connect](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID#openid-connect). The aim of this migration is to map the old `fedId` field to new the Google+ User Ids.

This allows us to retrieve an OpenID identifier using an existing OAuth 2.0 process.

*Caveat:* The Google .NET Client APIs do not support this migration path. So authentication must be done manually or using a [3rd party OAuth library](http://dotnetopenauth.net/).

**Howto:**

- As per usual OAuth flow, direct the user to the Authenticate endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth) with the following variables:

  - **openid.realm=`http://localhost`** ** Required, where `http://localhost` matches your redirect_uri variable
  - **scope=openid profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly** ** Both `openid` and `profile` scopes are required in order to retrieve the OpenID identifier. The `chromewebstore` scope is required to query the payments API.
- Then exchange the code for an access token from the Token endpoint (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token)

  - At this point you will receive the standard `access_token`, `refresh_token`, etc variables but also an additional `id_token` variable.
  - This `id_token` is a JWT-encoded string containing the OpenID information.
  - Decoding this JWT-encoded (you can use this [C# JWT Library](https://github.com/johnsheehan/jwt)) string will give you a JSON string in the following format:

  `{
      "aud": "<googleuserid>.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
      "at_hash": "<hashcode>", 
      "iss": "accounts.google.com", 
      "openid_id": "<!! The fedId we require !!>", 
      "exp": <id>, 
      "azp": "<googleuserid>.apps.googleusercontent.com", 
      "iat": <id>, 
      "sub": "<googleuserid>"
  }`

  - At this stage we've finally found what we're looking for, the `openid_id`. This can be used to communicate with the Chrome Payments API
- While still using the same OAuth credentials, make a signed request to the following URL:

  - `https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1/licenses/{appId}/{openId}`
  - `{appId}` is the ID of your app within the Chrome Web Store
  - `{openId}` is the `openid_id` from the JWT response

Comment: After implementing this I found out that the above only works if you authorize as a user account who has permission to view the project on your Chrome Developer Dashboard. Meaning you have to authorize as a specific user, rather than the current user, to perform this check.

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you need:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

Its a complete overview of OAuth2.0.

Helped me with a problem I was having with a webapp setup, hope it can do the same.

P.S - Im not sure but this may be exactly what your looking for:

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp